# Eclipse - Can't edit cpp files in my eclipse - folder is not accessible

Tags: c++, eclipse, file

i want to edit cpp files in Eclipse but can't open the folder that contains the cpp files.
The folder symbol is a folder with an exclamation mark at the bottom right. I tried to look up the meaning of the symbol in the eclipse docs but didnt find something. Maybe a bit more background: the cpp files belong to a cocos2d-x application, eclipse cdt is installed. The files are normally accessible with notepad++ or any other texteditor but eclipse just doesn't list them. Refresh, clean or restart didnt help either. Maybe you guys can help me out.

Comment: Most probably that's a _virtual folder_ pointing to some pat that's not present at your actual filesystem. Did you import the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, a little fault in the path, edited the folder properties now everything works!

Answer (score 1):

The esclamation Mark deals with build path problem. This problem are usually related with eclipse metadata, probably rebuilding the Index Will fix it, but the easiest thing is delete the project (without deleting from disk) and import the project using import existing project into workspace. Male a backup before any operation.